# Rental Rate calculations

Tags: java

Hi everyone I'm currently attending a java class for my degree and I was given an assignment to calculate rental rates, so far I was able to get the code but my errors are way to persistent and I feel like I'm really close but it definitely needs some adjustments. If anyone is willing to take the time and let me know what I could add or take out that would be awesome.

**Here are the errors:**

```
RentalRates.java:117: error: illegal start of expression
         private static clacGen(s.gender);
         ^
RentalRates.java:117: error: illegal start of expression
         private static clacGen(s.gender);
                 ^
RentalRates.java:117: error: ';' expected
         private static clacGen(s.gender);
                               ^
RentalRates.java:117: error: not a statement
         private static clacGen(s.gender);
                                 ^
RentalRates.java:117: error: ';' expected
         private static clacGen(s.gender);
                                        ^
RentalRates.java:133: error: illegal start of expression
         private static calcAge(birthMonth,birthDay,birthYear);
         ^
RentalRates.java:133: error: illegal start of expression
         private static calcAge(birthMonth,birthDay,birthYear);
                 ^
RentalRates.java:133: error: ';' expected
         private static calcAge(birthMonth,birthDay,birthYear);
                               ^
RentalRates.java:133: error: not a statement
         private static calcAge(birthMonth,birthDay,birthYear);
                                ^
RentalRates.java:133: error: ';' expected
         private static calcAge(birthMonth,birthDay,birthYear);
                                          ^
RentalRates.java:133: error: not a statement
         private static calcAge(birthMonth,birthDay,birthYear);
                                           ^
RentalRates.java:133: error: ';' expected
         private static calcAge(birthMonth,birthDay,birthYear);
                                                   ^
RentalRates.java:133: error: not a statement
         private static calcAge(birthMonth,birthDay,birthYear);
                                                    ^
RentalRates.java:133: error: ';' expected
         private static calcAge(birthMonth,birthDay,birthYear);
                                                             ^
RentalRates.java:136: error: ';' expected
            today_date = curMonth,curDay,curYear
                                 ^
RentalRates.java:136: error: not a statement
            today_date = curMonth,curDay,curYear
                                  ^
RentalRates.java:136: error: ';' expected
            today_date = curMonth,curDay,curYear
                                        ^
RentalRates.java:155: error: illegal start of expression
         private static String calcRateClass(age, gender);
         ^
RentalRates.java:155: error: illegal start of expression
         private static String calcRateClass(age, gender);
                 ^
RentalRates.java:155: error: ';' expected
         private static String calcRateClass(age, gender);
                              ^
RentalRates.java:162: error: illegal start of expression
         private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
         ^
RentalRates.java:162: error: illegal start of expression
         private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
                 ^
RentalRates.java:162: error: ';' expected
         private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
                                      ^
RentalRates.java:162: error: not a statement
         private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
                                       ^
RentalRates.java:162: error: ';' expected
         private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
                                             ^
RentalRates.java:162: error: not a statement
         private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
                                               ^
RentalRates.java:162: error: ';' expected
         private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
                                                  ^
RentalRates.java:162: error: not a statement
         private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
                                                    ^
RentalRates.java:162: error: ';' expected
         private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
                                                              ^
```

29 errors

WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN:__________________________________

Welcome to the car renter's rate finder.

enter code here Please enter the renter’s gender (m/f):m

Please enter today's date (mm dd yyyy): 10 4 2011

Please enter the renter’s date of birth (mm dd yyyy): 1 22 1990

Thank you.

The male renter is 21 years old.

The rate class is: Sorry, the renter is not 25 years of age or older.

CODE:__________________________________

```
enter code here
import java.util.*;

public class RentalRates
{
private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

private static final String BEST_RATE = "Best rate - $40.00 per day or   $200.00 per week.";
private static final String RISK_RATE_1= "Risk rate 1-$50.00 per day or $255.00 per week.";
private static final String RISK_RATE_2= "Risk rate 2-$57.00 per day or $285.00 per week.";
private static final String RISK_RATE_3= "Risk rate 3-$%4.2f per day or $%5.2f per week.";

public static void main(String[] args)
{    
  int curMonth = 0;
  int curDay = 0;
  int curYear = 0;
  int birthMonth = 0;
  int birthDay = 0;
  int birthYear = 0;
  String gender = "";
  int age = 0;
  String rateResult;            



  if (DEBUG == true)
  {
    // Establish a 'current' date for testing...
     curMonth = 2;
     curDay = 1;
     curYear = 2016;

     System.out.println("First test case: Renter is not old enough to rent...");
     birthMonth = 2;
     birthDay = 2;
     birthYear = 1991;
     gender = "m";
     age = calcAge(curMonth, curDay, curYear, birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
     rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender);
     displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);

     System.out.println("\nSecond test case: Renter is barely old enough (57/285)...");
     birthMonth = 2;
     birthDay = 1;
     birthYear = 1991;
     gender = "m";
     age = calcAge(curMonth, curDay, curYear, birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
     rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender);
     displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);

     System.out.println("\nThird test case: Renter is 35 and male (40/200)...");
     birthMonth = 1;
     birthDay = 1;
     birthYear = 1981;
     gender = "m";
     age = calcAge(curMonth, curDay, curYear, birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
     rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender);
     displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);

     System.out.println("\nFourth test case: Renter is 35 and female (40/200)...");
     birthMonth = 1;
     birthDay = 1;
     birthYear = 1981;
     gender = "f";
     age = calcAge(curMonth, curDay, curYear, birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
     rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender);
     displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);

     System.out.println("\nFifth test case: Renter is 30 and male (57/285)...");
     birthMonth = 1;
     birthDay = 1;
     birthYear = 1986;
     gender = "m";
     age = calcAge(curMonth, curDay, curYear, birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
     rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender);
     displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);

     System.out.println("\nSixth test case: Renter is 30 and female (40/200)...");
     birthMonth = 1;
     birthDay = 1;
     birthYear = 1986;
     gender = "f";
     age = calcAge(curMonth, curDay, curYear, birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
     rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender);
     displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);

     System.out.println("\nSeventh test case: Renter is 76 and male (62/255)...");
     birthMonth = 1;
     birthDay = 1;
     birthYear = 1940;
     gender = "m";
     age = calcAge(curMonth, curDay, curYear, birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
     rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender);
     displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);        

     System.out.println("\nEighth test case: Renter is 76 and female (68/270)...");
     birthMonth = 1;
     birthDay = 1;
     birthYear = 1940;
     gender = "f";
     age = calcAge(curMonth, curDay, curYear, birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
     rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender);
     displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);         
  }
  else
  {
     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Welcome to the car renter's rate finder.");
  // Get the gender...
  //    Your code goes here...
     private static clacGen(s.gender);
        {
         System.out.print("what is the Gender of the Renter? :");
         boolean f = female;
         boolean m = male;

         if (gender = "f")
         {
           return ("female");
         }

         else if (gender = "m")
         {
           return ("male");
         }                
     }         
     private static calcAge(birthMonth,birthDay,birthYear);
     {
        System.out.println("what is the Renters Bithday?(mm/dd/yy):");
        today_date = curMonth,curDay,curYear
        today_year = today_date.getFullYear();
        today_month = today_date.getMonth();
        today_day = today_date.getDate();
        age = today_year - birthYear;

        if ( today_month < (birthMonth - 1))
        {
           age--;
        }
        if (((birthMonth - 1) == today_month) && (today_day < birthDay))
        {
           age--;
        }
           return age;
      }


  // Get the rental rate...
     private static String calcRateClass(age, gender);
     {
        rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender);
        return rateResult;
     }

  // Display the results...
     private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
     {
        System.out.Println("Thank you");
        System.out.println("the ",gender," is ",age," years old.");
        System.out.println("the rate class is: ",rateResult);
     }
  }
```

}
}

Comment: You need to tell us what the errors are. What you expect and what is actually happening.

Comment: Sorry I just did that thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

I hate to break it to you, but you are not really close. This code is a mix of everything in one file and it's breaking all the rules. It demonstrates a lack of understanding of basic java concepts. This code is basically illegible.

Here are steps you can take to make your code and your compiler play nicer together. I present them in no particular order.

1) **Separate your production and test code:**

RentalsRate.java - should define the program behaviour. There are options for how to structure the code.  It looks like you are leaning towards static methods, which is fine if you are careful with your class variables. RentalRates.java class should define all of your methods statically.

RentalsRateTest.java should test the program. Your main function would contain all of your test cases(basically everything inside your `DEBUG == true`. The method calls with need some tweeking).

If you separate your test and production code you won't need the if/else statement and you will also be fine to get ride of the boolean DEBUG that is defined at the top.

2) **Functions require return values, or the keyword void**

For example, the following function declaration lacks a return value:

> `private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult)`

But the function needs to know what, if anything, it is suppose to hand back to it's caller once it is done doing it's job. If nothing is to be returned to the called then set the return value to the keyword `void`. At the very least, this way the function knows it's not supposed to give anything back to it's caller.

3) **Function input parameters require defined types**.

For example, the function `private static String calcRateClass(age, gender)` should read as `private static String calcRateClass(int age, char gender)`. If you don't define the input types in the function declaration, then how is the function supposed to know what in or is not valid input when it is called? Your compiler explodes and along with it, your homework assignment.

Knowing this, you should now go back and fix the declaration for `private static displayResults(gender, age, rateResult)` to also have type defined input parameters as well as all of your other functions

4) **Extract your methods**

Method definitions don't go inside of if/else statements. They are stand alone pieces of code. They may be called from within if/else statements of from elsewhere in the code but their definition should be such that it is on it's own. You currently have methods defined inside the else statement. This is wrong. In fact, if you do the 1) thing in my list this will no longer be an issue.

5) **Remove the ; from between the ) { in the method declarations.**

```
private static String calcRateClass(age, gender);
      {
```

should read as

```
private static String calcRateClass(int age, String gender) {
```

6) **Confusing Recursive Call**

This part here is a botched recursive call. If you don't know what that means, that's fine.

```
  private static String calcRateClass(age, gender);
     {
        rateResult = calcRateClass(age, gender);
        return rateResult;
     }
```

The problem, among many others, is that you are calling the function from inside itself. This is actually an infinite loop. Check your logic.

This is all I have to give right now. You have a ton of things that need work but if you start with these and come back demonstrating that you attempted to implement some basics I don't mind guiding you a bit more.